# Path of file in a exe

Tags: java, file, path, exe

I have a .exe with files and a main. My question is how I can call or reference this files with my main in Java.

```
File file = new File(".\\File");
//This take the file which are in the same folder that exe.
```

But I want take the file which are in the same .exe. I dont know if I explain well. Hope that someone can help me.

My main copy a file in a directory, I want that this file, be into the .exe, not in a extern folder.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you create your ``.exe`` file?

Comment: With the software "jexepack" because I created other program for select files and use jexepack with commands for create a new .exe with the files and the main in java which should copy the files in other directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review: [Understanding Directories and accessing your files](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html#directories)

Comment: Nice! I used System.getProperty("jexepack.resdir"); for take the temp files which jexepack make.

Really thanks :)